# Django ImportError: No module named tango_with_django_project.settings

Tags: python, django, runtime-error

From near the end of chapter 5 in the Tango With Django tutorial book, I have created a script used to populate a SQLite database with test data which is called:
`~/Workspace/wad2/tango_with_django_project/populate_rango.py`
After receiving an error, I tried directly copy-pasting the script from the book and still received the following errors:

```
H:\Workspace\wad2\tango_with_django_project>python populate_rango.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "populate_rango.py", line 7, in <module>
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 22, in setup
    configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 53, in __ge
tattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 41, in _set
up
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 97, in __in
it__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named tango_with_django_project.settings
```

**populate_rango.py**

```
import os

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE',
                      'tango_with_django_project.settings')

import django
django.setup()
from rango.models import Category, Page

def populate():

    python_pages = [
        {"title": "Official Python Tutorial",
         "url":"http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/"},
        {"title":"How to Think like a Computer Scientist",
         "url":"http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkpython/"},
        {"title":"Learn Python in 10 Minutes",
         "url":"http://www.korokithakis.net/tutorials/python/"} ]

    django_pages = [
        {"title":"Official Django Tutorial",
         "url":"https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial01/"},
        {"title":"Django Rocks",
         "url":"http://www.djangorocks.com/"},
        {"title":"How to Tango with Django",
         "url":"http://www.tangowithdjango.com/"} ]

    other_pages = [
        {"title":"Bottle",
         "url":"http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/"},
        {"title":"Flask",
         "url":"http://flask.pocoo.org"} ]

    cats = {"Python": {"pages": python_pages},
            "Django": {"pages": django_pages},
            "Other Frameworks": {"pages": other_pages} }

    for cat, cat_data in cats.items():
        c = add_cat(cat)
        for p in cat_data["pages"]:
            add_page(c, p["title"], p["url"])

    # Print out the categories we have added.
    for c in Category.objects.all():
        for p in Page.objects.filter(category=c):
            print("- {0} - {1}".format(str(c), str(p)))

def add_page(cat, title, url, views=0):
    p = Page.objects.get_or_create(category=cat, title=title)[0]
    p.url=url
    p.views=views
    p.save()
    return p

def add_cat(name):
    c = Category.objects.get_or_create(name=name)[0]
    c.save()
    return c

# Start execution here!
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Starting Rango population script...")
    populate()
```

**models.py**

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Categories'

    def __str__(self): 
        return self.name

class Page(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    url = models.URLField()
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self): 
        return self.title
```

**settings.py** (relevant code)

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'tango_with_django_project', 'templates')
STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'tango_with_django_project', 'static')
MEDIA_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'tango_with_django_project', 'media')
```

**Locations**

```
~/Workspace/wad2/manage.py  
~/Workspace/wad2/tango_with_django_project/populate_rango.py  
~/Workspace/wad2/tango_with_django_project/settings.py
```

Does anyone know what might be the cause of these errors?
It seems that a common cause of this is the wrong folder name, but my script is in the `tango_with_django_project` folder which is specified in my `os.environ.setdefault` line already.
If any other files would be useful, I can add them.

Comment: Please show the layout of your project.

Comment: @Alasdair in what way?  Would you like my settings.py file or any terminal output in particular?

Comment: You haven't shown the *layout* of your files, e.g. the location of `settings.py` and `populate_rango.py`.

Comment: @Alasdair, edited to include layout

Comment: @Paradox quick question: do you have `__init__.py` in `with_django_project` ?

Comment: @Dawid Yes, I do, though it is an empty file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order for your Django project to load the settings as `tango_with_django_project.settings`, `wad2` needs to be on the Python path.

The easiest fix is to move `populate_rango.py` up a directory from `wad2/tango_with_django_project/` to `wad2`.

Alternatively, you can add the parent directory to the python path in `populate_rango.py`

```
import sys
sys.path.append('..')

import os
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE',
                      'tango_with_django_project.settings')
```